# -bash error when trying to run --help command

Tags: python, terminal

I am trying to run a --help command with a .py file but I get this error:

```
-bash: ./unicorn.py: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you give us some details about unicorn.py? Have you checked if there is a file on your machine called python3 inside /usr/bin?

Comment: Sounds like `/usr/bin/python3` doesn't exist. Have you checked? Maybe your `python3` is installed somewhere else, like `/bin/python3` or `/usr/local/bin/python3`. Run `type python3` to check. Also, what command did you run exactly?